# How to create a middleware for check role in Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to create a middleware for check role of my users.

```
// middleware/is-admin.js
export default function (context) {
  let user = context.store.getters['auth/user']

  if ( user.role !== 'admin' ) {
    return context.redirect('/errors/403')
  }
}
```

In my `.vue` file, I'm putting this on:

```
middleware: [ 'is-admin' ]
```

It works.

Now, I'd like to check if the user also has another role. So, I create a new middleware:

```
// middleware/is-consultant.js
export default function (context) {
  let user = context.store.getters['auth/user']

  if ( user.role !== 'consultant' ) {
    return context.redirect('/errors/403')
  }
}
```

And in my `.vue` file:

```
middleware: [ 'is-admin', 'is-consultant' ]
```

Unfortunately, when I do that, if I visit the route with an administrator role, it does not work anymore.

Can you tell me how I can create a middleware that checks multiple roles with Nuxt.js?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

The idea is that every page has its authority level. Then in middleware you can compare your current user authority level with the current page authority level, and if it's lower redirect the user. It's very elegant solution that was proposed by Nuxt.js creator. [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1687#issuecomment-331870619).

```
<template>
  <h1>Only an admin can see this page</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'auth',
  meta: {
    auth: { authority: 2 }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in your `middleware/auth.js`:

```
export default ({ store, route, redirect }) => {
  // Check if user is connected first
  if (!store.getters['user/user'].isAuthenticated) return redirect('/login')

  // Get authorizations for matched routes (with children routes too)
  const authorizationLevels = route.meta.map((meta) => {
    if (meta.auth && typeof meta.auth.authority !== 'undefined')
      return meta.auth.authority
    return 0
  })
  // Get highest authorization level
  const highestAuthority = Math.max.apply(null, authorizationLevels)

  if (store.getters['user/user'].details.general.authority < highestAuthority) {
    return error({
      statusCode: 401,
      message: 'Du måste vara admin för att besöka denna sidan.'
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this feature in Nuxt

```
export default function ({ $auth, redirect }) {
  if (!$auth.hasScope('admin')) {
    return redirect('/')
  }
}
```

The scope can be anything you want e.g Consultant, Editor etc.

Check the [documentation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth.html#hasscope-scopename)

### Updated

Since you are using Laravel
You can have a role column in your user table 
e.g

```
$table->enum('role', ['subscriber', 'admin', 'editor', 'consultant', 'writer'])->default('subscriber');
```

Then create a API resource, check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources) for more

To create a user resource, run this artisan

```
php artisan make:resource UserResource
```

Then in your resource, you can have something like this

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'phone' => $this->phone,
        'gender' => $this->gender,
        'country' => $this->country,
        'avatar' => $this->avatar,
        'role' => $this->role,
   ];    
}
```

Then you can import it to your controller like this

```
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
```

You can get the resource like this

```
            $userdata = new UserResource(User::find(auth()->user()->id));
            return response()->json(array(
                'user' => $userdata,
            ));
```

### In Nuxt

To do authentication in Nuxt

> Install nuxt auth and axios

```
Using YARN : yarn add @nuxtjs/auth @nuxtjs/axios
Or using NPM: npm install @nuxtjs/auth @nuxtjs/axios
```

Then register them in your `nuxtconfig.js`

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
  ],
```

In your `nuxtconfig.js`, add this also

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'
  },

auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'access_token' },
          logout: { url: '/logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false }
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'Bearer',
        globalToken: true
        // autoFetchUser: true
      }
    }
  }
```

The URL been the endpoints

Check [Documentation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup.html) for more

To restrict certain pages in Nuxt to Specific User.
> Create a middlweare e.g isadmin.js

Then add this

```
export default function ({ $auth, redirect }) {
  if (!$auth.hasScope('admin')) {
    return redirect('/')
  }
}
```

Then go to the Page, add the middleware

```
export default {
  middleware: 'isadmin'
```

Comment: May I ask how can I feed nuxt the user roles? Do I need to have a role list in user object ( `this.$auth.user` ) ? I'm using Nuxt with Laravel (API server) btw.

Comment: Thanks for the Laravel walkthrough. My issue is more on the Nuxt side though. I use Nuxt Auth module so it auto-fetches user data through `/user` endpoint. Right now I have added a `role` key added to user from laravel side, BUt I don't know how to check for that role in Nuxt

Comment: Check my updated answer. Let me know if this solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I looked into auth module source code and found that the `hasScope` method (by default) looks for a `scope` key in user object. So we have to change the `role` name to `scope` so Nuxt auth module can process it. Obviously we can also keep role name on laravel side and change `scopeKey` on the nuxt auth module options.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.